# Behaviour in regex validation

Tags: ruby, operator-precedence

I tried to validate a path, and if the path doesn't match with the regex, then I applied a logic. I get the expected result in the following:

```
path = 'banner/gwd_preview_/index.html'
/^__MACOSX/.match(path).nil? and /gwd_preview_/.match(path).nil?
# => false
```

But when I store the regex validation in a variable:

```
is_valid_path = /^__MACOSX/.match(path).nil? and gwd_preview_/.match(path).nil?
# => false
```

and call for the result of `is_valid_path`, I get `true`:

```
is_valid_path # => true
```

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=` has stronger precedence than `and`. First, you assigned to `is_valid_path` the result of the first `nil?`, which turned out to be `true`. Then the second `nil?` returned `false`. The conjunction, then became `false`.

Comment: you should stick to `&&` and `||` for boolean expressions. `and` is not the same as `&&`.